# Apache CXF - handle response with HTTP 400 code

Tags: java, http, cxf

I am using SOAP client, generated with Apache CXF framework.
Service that I am trying to connect to handles business errors with soap:Fault messages.
I want to interpret these massages and handle them appropriately.
Unfortunately those responses has HTTP status 400 (Bad request).
As a result response body is not interpret in my client, stream is closed and I cannot process them correctly.
In the contrary, message is correctly interpreted in SoapUI client.

Let me know if there is any way to parse those responses.
Maybe there is some kind of interceptor to override.

Thanks and Best Regards