# How to get response body if server send status 400/500

Tags: cxf

I need to implement a web service client for a third-party web service. Unfortunately the web service operator decided to send a HTTP status code 400 if a "normal" fault occurred. That means if something is going wrong the web service sends something like this in the body

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>ERROR</faultcode>
         <faultstring>[M0002] The following dealer information was not accepted. [C07AB02157XX]</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and sets the HTTP-StatusCode to 400 and Content-Type to 'text/xml'. This results in a `WebServiceException` in my code which does not contain the Fault itself. In such case my stacktrace looks like this:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.mapException(JaxWsClientProxy.java:183)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.dihMessage(Unknown Source)
    at de.dmsserver.core.service.manufacturer.hyundai.dih.masterdata.MasterDataContext.requestSinglePartNumber(MasterDataContext.java:154)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '400: Bad Request' when communicating with [...]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1618)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1625)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1570)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1371)
    at org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingOutputStream.postClose(LoggingOutputStream.java:53)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:528)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:439)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:354)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:312)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
    ... 11 more
```

Now I can not figure out how to get access to the original body with the Fault itself.

I played a bit and adding my own OutInterceptors with Phase.SEND

```java
class MyOutInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    public MyOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.SEND);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFault(Message message) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In such a case the handleFault method is fired, but I can't figure out how to access the response body as `message.getContent(InputStream.class)` returns null.

It seems that [Apache CXF - handle response with HTTP 400 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484749/apache-cxf-handle-response-with-http-400-code) is exactly my problem. Unfortunately this question was not solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a solution for this problem after digging more about this in the net.
I've found this request in apache jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4241
This solved my problem!